# Use firebase storage and real-time database so when upload an image from the firebase admin panel a node in the real-time database is created

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I am trying to use Firebase storage and Firebase real-time database together such that when I upload an image file from the Firebase console to my app's storage bucket, a node in the real-time database is created containing the uploaded image download url, image title and other metadata.

The reason for this is that I don't want to be storing loads of data in the image metadata and need to be able to query the metadata for filtering and search in my android app, which is why I think using the real-time database is better.

Is this possible from the Firebase console and how would I go about implementing this? As far as I can see there isn't much help on how to do this on the firebase documentation and on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot achieve this by using only the Firebase Console. You need to do it programmatically. This is also the reason why you cannot find much in the Firebase documentation. To upload an image, you can see this [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mSi7bNk4ySM).

Comment: Is there everything alright? Can i help you with other informations?